# Using JobControl in Oozie Java action

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Can you use JobControl in Oozie Java action to start a sequence of jobs? And do you find it "natural"?

I'm having a sequence of jobs where output of one job is input to another and I'm considering using JobControl to organize the job flow and Oozie to start the job from a node in the cluster (not from the client) and to perform scheduling of jobs. On the other hand, I don't want to organize a complicated workflow using Oozie, that is why I want to run a single Java action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job Control can be used in Oozie and it is natural. Oozie can have a single java action which invokes a sequence of jobs using Job Control.

Oozie running as a service in the cluster adds overhead to applications while job control just runs on the client machine.And therefore it is the best practice to use job control in Oozie java action instead of calling each of the jobs individually in Oozie in my opinion.